# Posting messages to facebook users using their facebook ID

Tags: mysql, facebook

I have created a page with a facebook login option for users with facebook account on my website.

When they login I store their basic information like thier id, name, and email.

Now I want to send messages/ post on their wall using the IDs I have stored of the facebook users in the database.

Is their any FB tool available or how can I do this using FB javascript to acheive the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Post` from the GraphAPI to post to their timeline  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

For obvious reasons of not turning Facebook into a source of spam, you cannot programatically send messages to users.